# "Commitment goes deeper than either of you are yet to realise." — What does "yet" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sentences/english/either):
**(1)** *Commitment goes deeper than either of you are **yet** to realise*.

The phrase "*are yet to*" is strange to me.
What does "*yet*" mean here?
Could you show me please in a dictionary that meaning of "*yet*" which would be appropriate for this example?

Comment: The usual meaning - _until now_. The sense is 'than either of you has realised yet'.

Comment: @KateBunting In other words, you're saying "yet" in (1) means "already". I thought "yet" and "already" always have different meanings.

Comment: @Loviii They don't have the same meaning, they have opposite meanings. Already means that a thing has happened at the said point in time, yet means that it has not.

Comment: No, I'm not saying that. _Yet_ usually follows a negative (they have not realised it  so far) - _already_ means that something _has_ happened before now, perhaps sooner than expected.

Comment: Note to downvoters and close-voters: This fits the pattern that we ask for; the asker shows that they've looked it up in a dictionary, what they found, and how they're still confused. Perhaps the search should have been more thorough, but it does fit the bill.

Comment: @KateBunting There isn't negation in "_than either of you are yet to realise_" and in "_than either of you has realised yet_", so the meaning of "yet" for the negation isn't appropriate for these phrases.

Comment: @KateBunting When I saw you'd written "_The sense is 'than either of you has realised yet'_" - I thought you meant  "_than either of you has realised **yet**_" means "_than either of you has **already** realised_". But you said "no". And this isn't clear to me. If you're saying "yet" means "until now" here, and considering the fact that "already" means "before now", then "until now" and "before now" mean the same here. Then why did you say "no"?

Comment: Not an explicit negative, but an implied one - 'neither of you has realised it yet'. YonKuma and I have both explained that we use _already_ when something has happened and _not yet_ when it hasn't.

Comment: @KateBunting You said there's an implied negative in (1). I'd never think so. Could you tell me please by what word this negative is expressed in (1)? By the word "than"?

Comment: @Loviii "[X]er than you have [Y]" implies that "you have not [Y] that [X]," so it is an implicitly negative sentence. "Higher than you have gone" = "You have not gone that high". "Deeper than you have realized" = "You have not realized that depth"

Comment: @YonKuma You wrote "[X]er than you have [Y]" where "have [Y]" is a verb in the perfect tense. But (1) does not have Perfect. The phrase "_are yet to realise" is written in the present tense so it doesn't say what was in the past.

Comment: @Loviii As explained in the answer, "yet to [Y]" is an implicitly negative construction meaning that you have not done [Y], at least up until the "now" conveyed by "yet". Kate gave an equivalent sentence that is used more often. All formulations are implicitly negative. "[X]er than you've yet to [Y]" = "have not [Y]ed that [X] yet" = "[X]er than you have [Y]ed yet". It's all equivalent, and all implies that you haven't taken action [Y] to the degree of reaching [X].

Answer (score 1):

According to [the same Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/yet), this is definition 7:

> If you say that you have yet to do something, you mean that you have never done it, especially when this is surprising or bad.

Roughly, this sentence can be rewritten as "Committment goes deeper than either of you have realized yet," or "Neither of you have realized up to now how deep commitment goes."

Answer (score 1):

A better sentence would have **than either of you yet realize**, meaning: in the future one or both of you may know how deep commitment goes, but you do not know it now.

As it is, it is a strange way to say that even your future understanding (that which “you are yet to realize”) will be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

As an American English speaker, I find this sentence deeply awkward in its phrasing. It is either a British locution with which I am unfamiliar, or bad writing, or both.

(But yes, with a bit of effort I would interpret this as "...than either of you have realized yet", as others have pointed out.)